# changing d3 class on mouseover

Tags: d3.js, mouseover

I'm using d3 v4 and trying to apply a style to an element on mouseover.
I'm wondering if it's an API change with V4 but I can't seem to get at the node

I have code:

```
.on('mouseover', () => {
  let self = d3.select(this);
  let c = self.attr('class');
```

but this gives an error

```
Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

So the `d3.select()` doesn't seem to work...
The mouseover IS firing however.

I can use

```
.on('mouseover', (elem) => {
  console.log('elem', elem);
```

Which will give me some type of D3 object, but not a DOM node.
I can't use any D3 methods on this object

```
  elem.classed("hilite", true);
  elem.attr("class", "hilite");
```

Neither of those methods exist on a d3 returned object.

So how do I do this super basic operation in d3?

related to
[Change class of one element when hover over another element d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919708/change-class-of-one-element-when-hover-over-another-element-d3)

Comment: If this is TypeScript, could you please provide JavaScript code which it generated (or perhaps a fiddle)? d3.select should be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/hjt5rxbx/

Comment: Can you do a fiddle for this ?

Comment: There is no need for a fiddle, this is just the meaning of `this` in a fat arrow function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use arrow functions (if this an arrow function), if you don't need access to `this` of the current element. In this case you do need, because D3 calls event handlers setting `this` to the element triggering this event.

See: [Using arrow functions with d3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32881162/343261)